# Changing vector in function by pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector, append

Newbie in cpp, cannot understand what's going wrong:

```
void addElem(vector<someCustomByteType> *result, string str_to_add) {
  someCustomByteType *elem = (someCustomByteType*)str_to_add.data();
  int elem_size = str_to_add.size();
  memcpy(&(*result).back(), elem, elem_size);
}
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  vector<someCustomByteType> vec(5);
  vector<someCustomByteType> *vec_ptr = &vec;
  addElem(signed_string_ptr, "abcd");
  return 0;
}
```

outside, in main:

vector not changed outside. But memcpy works. What's going on?
Thank you!

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] please. Beyond that, I suggest you compile with *all* and *extra* warnings enabled. See what that brings up.

Comment: `memcpy` overwrites existing memory. It doesn't add new memory to a vector.

Comment: `back()` returns a reference to the last element in the vector, and then `memcpy` proceeds to overwrite everything in memory that follows it, corrupting everything in sight. Only fortune prevents your code from crashing.

Comment: @user2501323 Why is the vector passed to the function by means of a pointer?

Comment: @StoryTeller, edited as you say.

Comment: Please explain what it is you are trying to do with that code.  (What it does do is undefined behavior, in particular corrupting the heap) .  Are you trying to add each character of `str_to_add` to the back of `*result`?

Comment: You need to [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) each letter in the string. [Converting std::string to std::vector](//stackoverflow.com/q/8247793)

Comment: Trying to do things with vector like an array - with array all works, but not for vector. Trying to use pointers not to use params by reference.

Comment: More better use emplace_back()

Comment: What is `someCustomByteType`, and how do you mean to convert a string of `char`s to whatever this type is?

Comment: @interjay, that doesn't matter. Constructor exists, it works. Problem is vector not changing.

Comment: Of course it matters. This question can't be answered without knowing what we're dealing with. If you don't post a [mcve] this question will just get downvoted and closed.

Comment: No problem, really. I want to do it myself, not know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function does not make sense.

For starters it is unclear why you are using a pointer to the vector instead of a reference to the vector.

Nevertheles, this declaration

```
vector<unsigned char> vec(5);
```

does not reseeve a memory for the vector. It initializes the vector with 5 zero-characters which will be appended with other characters in the function.

The expression

```
&(*result).back()
```

returns reference to the last element of the vector.  And this call

```
memcpy(&(*result).back(), elem, elem_size);
```

will try to overwrite memory that does not belong to the vector. As result the function has undefined behaviour.

Youy can imagine the situation the following way

```
   vector
|0|0|0|0|0|
        |a|b|c|d|
         string
```

so as it is seen there is an attempt to copy characters 'b', 'c', and 'd' to the memory that does not belong to the vector.

You should use methods of the class template `std::vector` to append new elements.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program (provided that you want to use a pointer to vector).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void addElem( std::vector<unsigned char> *result, const std::string &str_to_add ) 
{
    result->reserve( result->size() + str_to_add.size() );
    result->insert( result->end(), str_to_add.begin(), str_to_add.end() );
}   

int main() 
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
    std::vector<unsigned char> *vec_ptr = &vec;

    addElem( vec_ptr, "abcd" );

    for ( auto c : *vec_ptr ) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
abcd
```

Comment: At last, understood that vectors cannot be used with custom types. Will try to find some another way

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is undefined behavior.  Neither `std::vector` or `std::string` are trivially copyable which is a requirement of `std::memcpy`.  If you want to copy a `std::string` into a `std::vector` you can just do something like

```
void addString(vector<unsigned char>& vec, const std::string& str)
{
    vec.assign(str.begin(), str.end());
}
```

Comment: Edit question a bit